# Shell Script combining two columns from txt file to another!

Tags: text-processing

I just would like to combine different txt files into one file using shell script;

The first text file has the values;

```
2.3444 5.66666
```

The second has the values;

```
4.5556 2.44444
```

I want combine them so that the final text file must be in the following format;

```
2.3444 5.66666
4.5556 2.44444
```

I tried the following scripts but it didn't work;

```
paste -d, all1.txt all1.25.txt > Results1.txt


awk 'NR==FNR {h[$2] = $3; next} {print $1,$2,h[$2]}' all1.txt all1.25.txt > file3.txt
```

Comment: Is the command you are looking for `cat`?

Comment: You should provide enough input and output to tell what's going on, or explicitly say that you want alternating lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify delimeter for paste "\n"

```
paste -d "\n" 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt > Results.txt
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply and help. The command works perfect for two txt files. However, If I had 3 or more txt file for instance, I got the following;                                                                                                                                                                                                       1.39928 12.6916
1.59022 13.1303,1.8251  13.7523

Comment: The third row doesn't have the same order!

Comment: I'm checked it and it work for many files, if there is different count of rows it put blank line.

Comment: I delete an `,` sign from code that was mistake.